# Detectada uma exceção não tratada. Código gerado: [68MJGTMV] e [XJEL5QC6] - Exception esperada

Tags: java, maven, hibernate, exceção

Caught an unhandled exception. Generated code: [68MJGTMV]: : javax.faces.FacesException: #{classeBean.salvar()}:

Verifiquei a classe especificada que esperar um valor de exception, mas não tem. O problema ocorreu quando migrei de pc.
O código está correto. Uso Maven, Jboss, Hibernate e Eclipse.

Como ingnorar esta exception esperada?
O projeto funicona, ao clicar na pa´gina salaBeans.xhtml (jsf) não abre a página e volta pra tela inicial.

Comment: `"O problema ocorreu quando migrei de pc"` Isso é indício de que o programa está fortemente atrelado a alguma característica do ambiente do PC original. Isso é considerado uma prática perigosa para a programação, então sugiro rever completamente o código que leva ao erro.

Answer (score 1):

Alguma classe ou função lançou uma Exception enquanto era executada fora de um bloco `try { } catch`. Isso pode ser por vários motivos. Você vai ter que ver o que a função `classeBean.salvar()` pode estar fazendo que causou esse erro.

Você pode achar que o código está correto, e talvez esteja mesmo, mas existem outros fatores externos a considerar.

Por exemplo, caso você esteja salvando em um arquivo, o caminho para esse arquivo existe? Mesmo que o programa seja capaz de criar o arquivo sozinho, ele não criará o caminho de pastas, e isso causará um erro inesperado ao tentar criar ou abrir o arquivo numa pasta que não existe.

Ou caso seja um banco de dados, ele ainda é capaz de conectar ao banco de dados? Pode ser que nessa mudança de PC você tenha esquecido de instalar o [SGBD](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_gerenciamento_de_banco_de_dados), criar o usuário/senha, ou tenha o criado com credenciais diferentes, ou pode ser que as tabelas não existam, ou que a biblioteca que o seu programa em Java está usando para se conectar seja incompatível com a versão do servidor.